# How can I load an SVG from an external file in SVGJS 3?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

How can I load an SVG from an external file in SVGJS 3?  There are lots of examples for version 2.7 but I can't find any method which works in SVG.JS 3.  Even the one in the docs is not working for me:

The example from the docs is:

`var use  = draw.use('elementId', 'path/to/file.svg')`

So working this into my example, I was assuming the following code would work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.16/svg.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="svgimage" style="width: 1000px;height:1000px"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var draw = SVG();
        var image = draw.use('svgimage', 'image.svg')

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However I can see Chrome loads the "image.svg" file but it doesn't seem to do anything with it and there are no errors on the JS console.

If I inspect the DOM in F12, I can't see any sign of the SVG.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This code wouldn't work in 2.x either. It seems like you should read up on the `<use>` element. "use" does not load an image into the Dom were you can manipulate it. It's for mirroring existing elements. So when you call 'use' you pass in the ID of the element to be mirrored. However, you can also mirror elements from external svgs. Therefore you gave  second parameter were you can pass in  an URL. 
However, you can not manipulate the svg like that because 'use' creates a shadow Dom to display the element so its not editable. If that is already what you want, you can just load the svg image in an 'img' tag. However if you really want to manipulate the image after loading it, you have to make an Ajax request and physically put the svg into the Dom so svg.js can access it.

To your example: as pointed out, 'use' does not what you want. However there is a second mistake. You are never attaching the svg document to the Dom. A quick look into the Dom inspector should show you that.
What you want to do is use `SVG().addTo('#someId')`.
However, as discussed above, you most likely want to put the external svg into the Dom. So to pick up an SVG with svg.js which is already in the Dom, use `SVG(ID)`